# Describe Snowflake table from Azure Databricks

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to issue a `DESC TABLE` SQL command for a Snowflake table and using Azure Databricks but I can't quite figure it out! I'm not getting any errors but I'm not getting any results either. Here's the Python code I'm using:

```
options_vcp = {
  "sfUrl": snowflake_url,
  "sfUser": user,
  "sfPassword": password,
  "sfDatabase": db,
  "sfWarehouse": wh,
  "sfSchema": sch
}

sfUtils = sc._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils

sfUtils.runQuery(options_vcp, "DESC TABLE myTable")
```

I can download the Snowflake table using the `"sfDatabase"`, `"sfWarehouse"`, etc. values so they seem to be correct. I can run the `DESC TABLE` command in Snowflake and get correct results. But the only output I'm getting from databricks is this:

```
Out[1]: JavaObject id=o315
```

Does anyone know how to display this `JavaObject` or know of a different method to run `DESC TABLE` from Databricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From doc: [Executing DDL/DML SQL Statements](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#executing-ddl-dml-sql-statements):

> The **runQuery** method returns only TRUE or FALSE. It is intended for statements that do not return a result set, for example DDL statements like CREATE TABLE and DML statements like INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE. **It is not useful for statements that return a result set, such as SELECT or SHOW.**

Alternative approach is to use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/columns.html) view:

```
df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
    .options(sfOptions)
    .option("query", "SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name ILIKE 'myTable'")
    .load()
```

Related: [Moving Data from Snowflake to Spark](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#moving-data-from-snowflake-to-spark):

> When using DataFrames, the Snowflake connector supports SELECT queries only.
>
> Usage Notes
>
> Currently, the connector does not support other types of queries (e.g. SHOW or DESC, or DML statements) when using DataFrames.

Comment: Thank you, this has been very helpful! Querying `information_schema.columns` doesn't provide all the information that `desc table` would but using `SELECT TABLE_NAME, column_name, ordinal_position, data_type, comment FROM information_schema.columns WHERE ...` gets me the information I need.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using get_ddl() in your select statement to get the object definition:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html

Comment: This can retrieve the definition of a table or a view. Good to know but not what I need at thjis time.

Comment: So you’re not able to use the select get_ddl() as part of a query via data frames?

Comment: Yes, what I've tried is

    df = spark.read \
      .format("snowflake") \
      .options(**options_vcp) \
      .option("query",  "select get_ddl('view', '{name of view}')") \
      .load()


That returns the definition of the view, but what I need is something similar to `DESC VIEW`, the column names, types, and especially the comments in my case